# How to setup Coverity Scan on GitHub with TravisCI?

Tags: c++11, github, cmake, travis-ci, coverity

I've managed to setup [TravisCI](https://travis-ci.org/) for my C++ hosted on Github [project](https://github.com/LeFlou/Citadel), it works fine.
I would like to move on to static analysis of my C++ code with [Coverity Scan](https://scan.coverity.com/).
Automatic upload with TravisCI to Scan Coverity is possible but I can't find a way to make it work.

My git repository is simple, there are two branches: `master` and `coverity_scan`.

To avoid triggering static analysis each time I'm pushing something, all stuff related to Scan Coverity is filled in `coverity_scan` branch:

```
language: cpp

env:
  global:
   # The next declaration is the encrypted COVERITY_SCAN_TOKEN, created
   #   via the "travis encrypt" command using the project repo's public key
   - secure: "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"

addons:
  coverity_scan:
    project:
      name: LeFlou/Citadel
    build_command_prepend: "cmake"
    build_command: "make"
    branch_pattern: coverity_scan
  apt:
    sources:
    - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
    packages:
    - gcc-4.8
    - g++-4.8
    - clang

compiler:
  - gcc
  - clang

before_script:
  - cmake .

script:
  - make

install:
# Use g++4.8 and not 4.6 (C++11 missing)
  - if [ "$CXX" = "g++" ]; then export CXX="g++-4.8" CC="gcc-4.8"; fi

branches:
  only:
    - coverity_scan
```

I want to trigger static analysis only when I push to `coverity_scan`, not building on TravisCI.
However, continuous integration must be working on `master` branch.

For the moment, code is only built but never uploaded to `Coverity Scan`.
What's wrong in my configuration ?

Edit:
I noticed in [TravisCI validator](http://lint.travis-ci.org) multiple addons generate errors, only the last entry is processed. On the other hand, `coverity_scan` seem to build without trouble (I need apt to install more recent versions of g++, this is related to C++11 features).

Edit 20150910:
I merged both `addons` sections and this works.
But I'm still stuck on "Submitted first build" step.
I also changed COVERITY_SCAN_TOKEN, still this does not submit the build to `Coverity Scan`
[TravisCI build with these changes](https://travis-ci.org/LeFlou/Citadel/builds/79745175)

Comment: What does it look like when you login to scan.coverity.com?

Comment: @ChrisBeck, I'm currently stuck on "Submitted first build" step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is in `build_command_prepend`, it's `cmake .` and not `cmake`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem might be that you indicated the branch you are using as `coverity_scan` here:

```
    branch_pattern: coverity_scan
```

but you said you are pushing to the branch `scan_coverity`. So you might want to try pushing to `coverity_scan` instead?

Comment: Unfortunately this is a mistake of mine, I use everywhere `coverity_scan`, I edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble too but got it working eventually.

First go to your "Project Settings" in Coverity. Copy the token

[Install the travis gem](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis.rb#installation) locally.

Then run:

```
travis encrypt -r <coverity_project_name> COVERITY_SCAN_TOKEN=<token>
```

For "coverity_project_name", use the name that is shown in your Coverity dashboard exactly as it appears.

You need to put the key generated by 'travis encrypt' into the "secure" field. So you should wind up with something like this:

```
- os: linux
  dist: bionic
  compiler: gcc
  env:
    - secure: "key generated by travis -r"
  before_install:
    - echo -n | openssl s_client -connect scan.coverity.com:443 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' | sudo tee -a /etc/ssl/certs/ca-
  addons:
    coverity_scan:
      project:
        name: "theimpossibleastronaut/rmw"
        description: "Console recycle bin written in C"
      notification_email:
      build_command_prepend: "./configure"
      build_command: "make"
      branch_pattern: coverity_scan
```